# transform recursively xml document with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am starting doing with xml and xslt, I also read some tutorials etc.. and according these as I understand this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<Menu>  
    <Accounts type="menu" label="Accounts">  
        <ListUsers type="cmd" label="List users">  
            <cmd>HAha</cmd>  
        </ListUsers>  
        <AddUsers type="cmd" label="Add users">  
            <cmd></cmd>  
        </AddUsers>  
        <DeleteUsers type="cmd" label="Delete users">  
            <cmd></cmd>  
        </DeleteUsers>  
    </Accounts>  
    <Hardware type="menu" label="Hardware">  
        <ListDisks type="cmd" label="List disks">  
            <cmd></cmd>  
        </ListDisks>  
    </Hardware>  
    <Network type="menu" label="Network"></Network>  
    <Filesystem type="menu" label="Filesystem"></Filesystem>  
</Menu>
```

and this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
<xsl:template match="/*">   
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>  
</xsl:template>  
<xsl:template match="*">  
    <div><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></div>  
</xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Should output labels of all elements, but it didn't... What I am missing, could you correct and explain me please, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two problems with this code**:

> ```
> <xsl:template match="*">       
>   <div>
>     <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
>   </div>   
> </xsl:template>
> ```

1. **Elements that aren't children of the top element (or the top element itself) are *not* processed at all**. To correct this, a new instruction should be appended to the body of the template -- for example: `<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>`
2. **Elements that don't have a `label` attribute will generate an empty `<div>`.** This can be avoided if a proper template match pattern is used so that the template is selected only for elements that do have this attribute.

**Here is a *complete* solution and it can be as short and simple as**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[@label]">
     <div><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></div>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Menu>
    <Accounts type="menu" label="Accounts">
        <ListUsers type="cmd" label="List users">
            <cmd>HAha</cmd>
        </ListUsers>
        <AddUsers type="cmd" label="Add users">
            <cmd></cmd>
        </AddUsers>
        <DeleteUsers type="cmd" label="Delete users">
            <cmd></cmd>
        </DeleteUsers>
    </Accounts>
    <Hardware type="menu" label="Hardware">
        <ListDisks type="cmd" label="List disks">
            <cmd></cmd>
        </ListDisks>
    </Hardware>
    <Network type="menu" label="Network"></Network>
    <Filesystem type="menu" label="Filesystem"></Filesystem>
</Menu>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<div>Accounts</div>
<div>List users</div>
<div>Add users</div>
<div>Delete users</div>
<div>Hardware</div>
<div>List disks</div>
<div>Network</div>
<div>Filesystem</div>
```

Comment: thanks this is what i wanted, could you please tell me why is different recursion between selecting all elements by asterisk and different when i select specified set of nodes, why in first case is creating nested divs and in this case not?

Comment: @anjalis: What is causing to go deeper in the XML tree is adding the `<xsl:apply-templates ...>` instruction -- this has nothing to do with the template match pattern. A fundamental rule in XSLT is that a template can only be selected for execution as result from an `<xsl:apply-templates...>` instruction -- otherwise it is not selected for execution.

Answer (score 4):

Well you should show us the output you want but if you want to process all elements then make sure you keep processing alive for all elements, either by flattening the hierarchy by changing

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:apply-templates select=".//*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or by using recursion by changing

```
<xsl:template match="*">
<div><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></div>
</xsl:template>
```

to something like

```
<xsl:template match="*">
<div>
  <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: nice and simple solution, thanks these things i didn't seen anywhere thanks, i thought that /* will select all child elements even nested as i see it's not true you must use that flattening (i must look closer on what it does) or recursion, thanks a lot

Comment: ahh i tried also dimitre solution and i see difference between those solution, your creates nested divs, which is not what is desirable, but thanks anyway, i understand more now how it works

Comment: Yes, right, the recursive approach I posted nests the divs (as that seemed one possible output you might want), the first suggestion which simply changes the `select="*"` to `select=".//*"` to process all descendants does not created a nested output.

Comment: i tried it first two elements aren't nested but than all elements are

Comment: Well it is difficult to exchange code in comments but my first suggestion results in the code sample `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">  
    <div><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></div>  
</xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>` and that way you get the output `<div>Accounts</div><div>List users</div><div/><div>Add users</div><div/><div>Delete users</div><div/><div>Hardware</div><div>List disks</div><div/><div>Network</div><div>Filesystem</div>`.